# Website will not scroll on mobile devices but only in desktop

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, scroll

This site: http://colombotaxi.com/ is not scrolling in mobile devices. I checked on Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini. Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the code that causes the error? What device is this website not scrollable on specifically? I can scroll just fine on my Smartphone and on the emulator in my developer tools.

Comment: Works on iPhone. Cannot replicate your problem. However, it lseems like you have some type of "smooth scroll" script hijacking the user scroll. Disable that and your issue will likely resolve.

Comment: It doesn't scrool in Samsung Galaxy s4 mini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styles.css line 1838: remove `body{ overflow:hidden; }`

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I commented that line still same issue mate

Comment: I reproduces the issue with decive emulation in Chrome and the issue was gone. Maybe it is something else. Goodluck! :)

Answer (score 0):

It scrolls for me on my LG Stylo (Android) in Chrome but the page scrolls very slowly. It looks like the page load has completed but something else is causing the slow scrolling. Maybe show us some code?